# Require Logic to avoid "StaleElementReferenceException" after page refresh

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, page-factory, staleelementreferenceexception

I am having multiple links on a Webpage. After clicking the link, a popup opens, I Set some values on fields in the popup and click on 'Save'.
[image: Web Main Page]

[image: Popup]

On clicking on 'Save', the main web page refreshes to show the updated status of the link. I use a "for" loop to iterate through all the Links one-by-one and update the status. To avoid stale element reference, I have written a utility to check if element is stale still but I am unable to get rid of this exception.

Below is my Utility code:

```
public static boolean isStale(WebElement e){
    try{
        e.isDisplayed();
        return false;
    }catch(StaleElementReferenceException ex){
        return true;
    }
}
```

Below is my page Objects code:

```
public class DocCheckPageObjects {

WebDriver driver = null;

public DocCheckPageObjects(WebDriver driver) {      
    this.driver = driver;
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, this); 
}

@FindBy(tagName="a")
WebElement tagName_a;
public WebElement tagName_a() { return tagName_a; }

@FindBy(xpath="//input[@name='progress']")
WebElement listBoxDocStatus;
public WebElement listBoxDocStatus() { return listBoxDocStatus; }

@FindBy(xpath="//span[@title='Received Hard Copy']")
WebElement listBoxDocStatusOptionReceivedHardCopy;
public WebElement listBoxDocStatusOptionReceivedHardCopy() { return listBoxDocStatusOptionReceivedHardCopy; }

@FindBy(xpath="//button[@name='update']")
WebElement btnSave;
public WebElement btnSave() { return btnSave; }

@FindBy(xpath="//*[contains(text(),'Saved Successfully')]")
WebElement toastMsg;
public WebElement toastMsg() { return toastMsg; }}
```

Below is my Class code:

```
DocCheckPageObjects docCheckObj = new DocCheckPageObjects(driver);
    WebElement docCheckTable = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='slds-gutters slds-wrap slds-m-horizontal_xx-small']/table"));
    
    System.out.println("No of Links: " + docCheckTable.findElements(By.tagName("a")).size());
    
    int linkCount =  docCheckTable.findElements(By.tagName("a")).size();
    
    for(int i=0; i<linkCount;i++) {                     
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(docCheckTable.findElements(By.tagName("a")).get(i)));
        docCheckTable.findElements(By.tagName("a")).get(i).click();
        docCheckObj.listBoxDocStatus().click();
        docCheckObj.listBoxDocStatusOptionReceivedHardCopy().click();
        docCheckObj.btnSave().click();
        while(util.isStale(docCheckTable.findElements(By.tagName("a")).get(i))) {
            docCheckTable = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='slds-gutters slds-wrap slds-m-horizontal_xx-small']/table"));
        }
    }
```

I think the code inside while loop is executing before the page is refreshed hence I am still getting Stale element exception.

Below is the code which works using thread.sleep:

```
for(int i=0; i<linkCount;i++) {     
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        docCheckTable = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='slds-gutters slds-wrap slds-m-horizontal_xx-small']/table"));
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(docCheckTable.findElements(By.tagName("a")).get(i)));
        docCheckTable.findElements(By.tagName("a")).get(i).click();
        docCheckObj.listBoxDocStatus().click();
        docCheckObj.listBoxDocStatusOptionReceivedHardCopy().click();
        docCheckObj.btnSave().click();          
    }
```

Q1) Above code resolves the state element reference, but i want to avoid using thread.sleep.

Q2) I had to put my locator like "docCheckTable" in my executable class instead of in Page Object factory class.  How do I put all my Locators in Page Object class which returns a list of Webelements and also avoids Stale Element exception.

Comment: Hello again, - a quick pass at Q1 - instead of the threadsleep, can you make sure the document is ready with some js `new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until((ExpectedCondition<Boolean>) wd ->
            ((JavascriptExecutor) wd).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete"));`   it doesn't work on all pages and depends on scripts type being run, but it's a quick thing to try :)

Comment: @RichEdwards Replaced thread.sleep with your code but got stale element exception after first iteration:

Comment: @RichEdwards Replacing thread.sleep with this one did the trick. wait.until(ExpectedConditions.stalenessOf(docCheckTable.findElements(By.tagName("a")).get(i)));